# MySQL EVENT error, PREPARE

Tags: mysql, events, concatenation, prepare

I need to move random numbers from column "car" to column "bar" every 10 minutes.
This my table:

```
+---+---+
|car|bar|
+---+---+
| 6 | 4 |
+---+---+
| 2 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

This my event

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `tezzt`;
CREATE EVENT tezzt
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO

SET @sums := ROUND( (
RAND( ) * ( 100 -10 ) ) +10
);
SET @vcar := 'car';
SET @vbar := 'bar';
SET @sql = CONCAT( 'UPDATE wp_users SET
`', @vcar , '`=`', @vcar , '`-', @sums,',','
`', @vbar , '`=`', @vbar, '`+', @sums
) ;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

And this my error

```
Error

SQL query:

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

@vcar and @vbar variables are very much needed. please, help

Comment: Check the user variable `@sql`, can't be NULL.